# Need to take a sample of all positions where user_id is not equal to ours

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Have 3 tables

users
posts
post_user (id, post_id, user_id)

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'posts';
public $timestamps = true;

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

}

```
class Users extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users';
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
}
```

}

Controller

```
 public function application()

{

    $posts = Post::find(1);
    $user = DB::table('post_user')->where('user_id', '=', $this->id)->lists('user_id');

    $posts = Post::whereNotIn('id', $user)->get();
    return View::make('applications')->with(array('posts' => $posts));


}
```

What am I doing wrong? If possible with an explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do `lists('post_id')`.

However there is a much nicer way with `whereDoesntHave`:

```
$userId = $this->id;
$posts = Post::whereDoesntHave('users', function($q) use ($userId){
    $q->where('user_id', $userId);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$this->id` contains your user id, try this:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('users', function($q) {
    $q->whereNotIn( 'id', [$this->id])
})->get();
```

Method `whereHas()` selects posts belonging users, which have met a condition within the Closure. And this condition - method `whereNotIn()` - check if user id is different form `$this->id`.